# rm command not able to use inside cluster

Tags: linux, rm

I am trying to delete any folder or files in my account inside the cluster using the rm command. But somehow I am not able to do this and getting an error

```
bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
/home/.../bin/rm: fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

Comment: looks like someone has redefined rm command to a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb). To delete a file use `/bin/rm` instead of `rm`.

Comment: yes /bin/rm is working. Is there any way so that I can use only rm for deleting a file instead of /bin/rm.

Comment: You have two options: either rename `/home/.../bin/rm` to `/home/.../bin/myrm` or edit it to replace all calls to `rm` inside this script with `/bin/rm`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple yet it might look complex as it shows itself in a rather unexpected way and is caused by not so simple process of command name resolution.

Let me remind you what happens when the shell executes a command like

```
command_name arg1 ... argn
```

1. The shell splits the command line into words separated by spaces and other *metacharacters*.
2. It takes the first word and treats at as a *command name*.
3. It checks if it contains slashes and if true treats it as a path to a command file and goes to #10
4. If the check in 3 fails It checks if *command name* is a name of a built-in command and executes the command if true
5. If the check in 4 fails it tries to find the command on the file system
6. It reads the `$PATH` variable and splits its value into segments separated by columns `:`.
7. For each segment it treats it as a path to a directory in the filesystem.
8. If the directory exists it scans the directory for an executable file name matching the *command name* if found it appends the command name to the directory name and treats this as a path to the command file and goes to #10
9. If the file is not found in any of the segments of the `$PATH` the shell reports an error.
10. The shell executes the command

```
command_file arg1 ... argn
```

Note the difference is that instead of `command_name` we have got `command_file` now.

Now what this has to do with your problem.

First your `$PATH` has `/home/.../bin` before `/bin`. So `rm myfile` becomes `/home/.../bin/rm myfile` instead of `/bin/rm myfile`.

Second your `/home/.../bin/rm` file is a shell script that calls `rm $*` or something like this. Executing this file results in a non terminating sequence of calls to `/home/.../bin/rm myfile`.

To check what command is being executed use the command `which rm`

**Option 1**

So one option would be to edit `/home/.../bin/rm` and replace all calls to `rm` with calls to `/bin/rm` in the file. Then it would not cause a non terminating sequence of calls.

**Option 2**

In general it is not a good idea to override standard commands unless you know very well what you are doing, so you could rename `/home/.../bin/rm` to `/home/.../bin/myrm`